# python open web page and get source code

Tags: python, pyqt

We have developed a web based application, with user login etc, and we developed a python application that have to get some data on this page.

Is there any way to communicate python and system default browser ?
Our main goal is to open a webpage, with system browser, and get the HTML source code from it ? We tried with python webbrowser, opened web page succesfully, but could not get source code, and tried with urllib2, in that case, i think we have to use system default browser's cookie etc, and i dont want to this, because of security.

Comment: The correct way is normally using urllib2, which *does* support cookies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

You can try to use Selenium, he was done for testing, but nothing prevents you from using it for other purposes

Comment: is there a way to selenium attach already opened browser ?
when i use, webdriver.Chrome() or, webdriver.Firefox() opens new.

Answer (score 0):

If your web site is navigable without Javascript, then you could try [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize) or [zope.testbrowser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser).  These tools offer a higher level API than `urllib2`, letting you do things like follow links on pages and fill out HTML forms.

This can be helpful in navigating a site that uses cookie based authentication with HTML forms for login, for example.

Comment: we use, lots of javascripts, most of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `nltk` module---they have some utilities for looking at web pages and getting text. There's also `BeautifulSoup`, which is a bit more elaborate. I'm currently using  both to scrape web pages for a learning algorithm---they're pretty widely used modules, so that means you can find lots of hints here :)